# How to make Email Button that populates an address from database?

Tags: php, email

I'm working on a site a bit like craigslist only very small scale.  I need help making a button that a user could click to email a seller of a particular item.  I need to populate the email with the seller's email address which is stored in a database.  This may be simple but I'm really new to php and not sure how to begin.  Could anyone help me with the code?  Very grateful for any help!

Comment: Why don't you, as beginner, start with php manual, and not with some project? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should implement a system where emails are not passed between users, both the seller and buyer should interface through your site with a contact system.

Comment: @lawrencecherone, do you have a tutorial you could refer me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hehe

- [php send an email tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp)
- [php tutorial read a database record](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php13p2.html)
- [php tutorial read form input](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php)

That is about what you need to do it.

These are the first links on Google when you search on those words. I quickly scanned the articles, they are all of decent quality. Don't forget there is always [php.net](http://www.php.net) for you aswell.

Good luck!

Comment: I was making my google searches way too complicated. Feeling very silly right now. Thanks for the help, Laoujin!